# JFrog Artifactory with VS, APIs, and DBs

Tags: deployment, artifactory, release-management

Can JFrog Artifactory be used to store deployment artifacts for promotion, for applications developed with Visual Studio ?

Also, can JFrog Artifactory be used for API deployment and DataBase deployment?

Comment: I have posted the answers for the other 2 queries below. Can you please elaborate more on the DB deployment part?

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is to have the .NET projects perform build and store artifacts from Visual Studio against the Artifactory, please follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/JFrog/project-examples/tree/master/msbuild-example). Additionally, if the query regarding API deployment is around the programmatic access against the Artifactory instance, please refer to [Artifactory REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API) wiki.